# hector_slam with Sick TIM561

Tags: slam, navigation, rplidar, ros-kinetic, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

we are working with a robot in a garage or production hall environment to test some car sensors. For mapping we tried an RPlidar (360°) with hector_mapping which is working very well out of the box. Unfortunally the RPlidar has problems to detect parts with black paint or car tires so we tried an Sick TiM561-2050101 which has an angle of 270° and better resolution.
Despite the higher frame rate (10Hz vs. 15Hz) and better resolution (0,9°/~400pts vs. 0,33°/~800pts) hector_mapping can't match the map on rotations. It's only working on very slow speeds. Mapping with linear movement seems to work on moderate speed.
We tried:

- reduce the frame rate
- reduce the number of points
- moved to a faster computer (from UDOO x86 Ultra on the robot to Intel NUC with i7 cpu)
- reduce the FOV

The laser data and slam_cloud is published with ~15Hz.

Why does it work out of the box with RPLidar but not with the Sick LIDAR?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284420/hector_slam-with-sick-tim561/) by [fehlfarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30134/fehlfarbe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2018-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was simple. We have an UDOO x86 Ultra on the robot where hector_slam is running and a control computer (Intel NUC) where the roscore and several other nodes are running. It seems the WiFi was too slow for the higher fps laser data (even with reduced points/fps/fov). We changed our access point from TP-Link Archer C5 to an Ubiquiti and now it's working great.

---

Originally posted by [fehlfarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30134/fehlfarbe/) with karma: 108 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0